# Shiny Dashboard boxes responsivity

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have two boxes in the first are two inputs and second box contains table. I use package DT for table. This setting is ok for resolution 1920x1080 but problem is in smaller resolution for example 1024x768

```
tabItem(tabName="Table",titlePanel("My Data"),


box(width=2,uiOutput("first_input"),textInput("numbers_input",label="choose your option",width ="200px")),

box(width=9,dataTableOutput("tabData"))

),
```

1024x768
[image]

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You havent really highlighted it, you dont want the scroll? You want 100% width? what is the problem?

Comment: @Pork Chop Problem is  that in smaller resolution the boxes are join.And I want boxes adjacent

Comment: The example below should be fine, be aware to open the app in browser. I dont know how rstudio viewer reacts to changes

Comment: I know but I tried view this in firefox and issue is same.

Comment: You should provide your full example, as the code below works perfectly on Firefox too

Comment: Ahh problem  is solved. In the css was set .box{min-width:200px} so thank you for help.

Comment: See its quite hard to help without knowing everything, glad you worked it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `scrollX = T`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItem(tabName="Table",titlePanel("My Data"),
            box(width=2,uiOutput("first_input"),textInput("numbers_input",label="choose your option",width ="200px")),
            box(width=9,dataTableOutput("tabData"))

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tabData <- renderDataTable({cbind(mtcars,mtcars)},options = list(scrollX = T))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```